# Arch Install wpa_supplicant from live arch to installed arch

Tags: linux, arch-linux, pacman, wpa-supplicant

I have arch installed on my hd, but I can't establish a WPA2-encrypted network connection because wpa_supplicant is not installed. On my arch live-usb there is wpa_supplicant and there I can establish the network connection.

Is there any way to tell pacman of my live arch to install the wpa_supllicant package to my installed arch on /mnt ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the `pacman` man page, it looks to me like you could do this:

```
pacman --root /mnt -S wpa_supplicant
```

while you have the "live Arch" CD booted, and the "/" partitioned mounted on `/mnt`.  That might be a little more complicated if you have a separate `/usr` partition.

You'll probably have to fix up the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file after you've rebooted from the HD, or fix it up in `/mnt/` before the reboot.

**UPDATE** 2017-04-02

Either Arch or `systemd` has changed. Here's what you do now:

1. Find wireless device name, use `ip a` or `ifconfig -a`  Mine is `wlp12s0`, USB wireless adaptors look  like `wlp26f7u3`
2. Start `wpa_supplicant`: `systemctl enable wpa_supplicant; systemctl start wpa_supplicant`. This is the master process, or maybe I'm just superstitious.
3. Make a `wpa_supplicant.conf@wirelessdevicename` file in `/etc/wpa_supplicant`. For my laptop, this is `wpa_supplicant-wlp12s0.conf` and I believe I just did `cp wpa_supplicant.conf wpa_supplicant-wlp12s0.conf`  There will exist a separate config file for each interface you start this way, and they can be configured differently.
4. Start `wpa_supplicant` for that inteface.  For me, this looked like: `systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlp12s0; systemctl start wpa_supplicant@wlp12s0`  You device name will vary.

It might help debug if you have `journalctl -f` running in a separate terminal.

Comment: "Start wpa_supplicant" How do you start it when it's not installed?

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown - I gave the command at the top of my answer: pacman --root /mnt -S wpa_supplicant

Comment: Thanks @Bruce . Turns out I was having a network issue and pacman is not good at dealing with flaky networks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pacstrap to install packages from your live usb to your Arch installation.

From your live usb:

First mount the partition your Arch is install to. (# is the number of the Arch partition)

```
mount /dev/sda# /mnt
```

Then use pacstrap to install the package to your mounted partition

```
pacstrap /mnt wpa_supplicant
```

Alternatively, you can also use the netctl package and the following command to establish a wireless connection without having to set up a wireless interface via ip link / wpa_supplicant. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl

```
sudo wifi-menu -o
```